# MS SQL calculation query - incorrect results and/or data type (only shows integer part)

Tags: integer, double, decimal

I've attached picture of the problem I'm having. Basically I am supposed to be getting answer like 3.66667 for first GPA, but it's showing 3. Same for the other 2 GPAs - they have decimal parts, but its not showing. What do you think is the problem? I already tried googling, changing data type etc... 
P.S. to get GPA:   divive TGP(Total Grade Points) by TCH (Total Credit Hours), however its only showing integer part...

here is the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcl6d.jpg